# Converting componentDidMount into useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, react-component

I am trying to learn React hooks, and trying to convert existing codebase to use hooks, but I am confused.
Is it normal to set state inside `useEffect`? Would I be causing the dreaded infinite loop if I do so?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import App from 'next/app';
import Layout from './../components/Layout';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    const [ cart, setCart ] = useState([]);

    const addToCart = (product) => {
        setCart((prevCartState) => {
            return [ ...prevCartState, product ];
        });
        localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));
    };

    //mimicking componentDidMount to run some effect using useEffect
    //useEffect(() => setCount((currentCount) => currentCount + 1), []);
    useEffect(() => {
        const cartCache = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
        //cart = cartCache; Good or bad?
        cartCache || setCart(() =>{

        });        
    }, []);
    return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}
```

My original class based component:

```
/*
export default class MyApp extends App {
  state = {
    cart: []
  }
  componentDidMount = () => {
    const cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
    if (cart) {
      this.setState({
        cart
      });
    }
  };
  addToCart = (product) => {
    this.setState({
      cart: [...this.state.cart, product]
    });
    localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(this.state.cart));
  }
  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps } = this.props
    return (
      <contextCart.Provider value={{ cart: this.state.cart, addToCart: this.addToCart }}>
        <Layout>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Layout>
      </contextCart.Provider>
    )
  }
}*/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's okey to set state inside `useEffect` as long as you don't listen to changes of the same field inside dependency array. In your particular case you are calling `useEffect` only once (since you have passed an empty dependency array).

```
useEffect(() => {
   const cartCache = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
   if (cartCache) {
      setCart(cartCache);   
   }     
}, []);
```

Also would be cool to add the second `useEffect` to listen to `cart` changes and keep the `localStorage` up-to-date.

```
useEffect(() => {
   localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));
}, [cart]);
```

Comment: I agree with the listening for changes part for your question with `useEffect`, that's why I upvoted this answer. Could you please check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64402467/converting-componentdidmount-into-useeffect/64402626#64402626) what you think about setting the initial state in `useState` as I suggest instead of using `useEffect` for that? Thanks!

Comment: what about `const cartLocalCache = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart')) || []; const [ cart, setCart ] = useState(cartLocalCache);`  and then useEffect to listen for cart changes using the recommendation by @kind user  ?

Comment: @AJSwift Its cool, also you could do `setCart(cartCache || [])`

Comment: @kinduser That's a good combination I believe of the suggested answers.

Comment: Thank you, great answers

Answer (score 2):

Because [`localStorage.getItem()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem) is a **synchronous** call thus for this scenario you can also use the function callback version of `useState` in order to set initial value. In this way you don't need to use `useEffect`. Usually if it is possible I try to avoid introducing any new side effects in my functional components.

You can try as the following instead:

```
const [ cart, setCart ] = useState(() => {
   const cartCache = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));

   if (cartCache) {
      return cartCache;
   }

   localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify([]));
   return [];
});
```

In this way if the `cart` element is missing from the `localStorage` the code will create it with a default `[]` empty array and set it also for your state. Other case it will set your state the value from storage.

**Please note:** Also I agree with [the answer from kind user here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64402467/converting-componentdidmount-into-useeffect/64402552#64402552) in terms of listening `cart` state changes to keep `localStorage` up to date with `useEffect`. My suggestion is only for the initial state.